# js date object yielding strange results

Tags: javascript, date, syntax

My date is in the format of `2011-04-01`. When I run the below code the following results.

```
var dateParts = '2011-04-01'.split('-');
dateParts[0] = parseInt(dateParts[0]);
dateParts[1] = parseInt(dateParts[1]);
dateParts[2] = parseInt(dateParts[2]);
console.log(dateParts);
for (i = 0; i <= 13; i++) {
  var thisDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1], dateParts[2] + i);
  console.log(thisDate);
}
```

Result:

```
[2011, 4, 1]
Date {Sun May 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
Date {Mon May 02 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
Date {Tue May 03 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
Date {Wed May 04 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
Date {Thu May 05 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
Date {Fri May 06 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
Date {Sat May 07 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
Date {Sun May 08 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
Date {Mon May 09 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
Date {Tue May 10 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
Date {Wed May 11 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
Date {Thu May 12 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
Date {Fri May 13 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
Date {Sat May 14 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)}
```

The date I split and the number I am giving the Date object are in April, why is it generating a date in May? I'm a bit new to JS so there may be something obvious I am missing. Any assistance or suggestions for improvements would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some JavaScript Date part arrays are zero based: e.g. Days: 0 => Sunday, Months: 0 => January

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Modified Code: http://jsfiddle.net/j4kBE/

Comment: Is only the month zero based? Both the day and the year are working correctly.

Comment: it's true, but please don't link to w3schools, as it's a terrible resource. see http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @wildcard - fair enough, new link ;)

Comment: @Icode4food, if you look at the developer.mozilla.org link, you should see that year and day return the actual year/day but month is 0 based (I guess because English and other European languages don't use numbers for months).

Comment: I find that sort of inconsistent but if it works I can't complain! Welcome to JS I suppose... :-)